# Proof that a collection of sets is a sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I need some help with this exercise:

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a measure space, $Y$ a non-empty set and $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ a function.

Define $\mathcal{N}=\{E\subseteq Y:\phi^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{M}\}$ and prove that $\mathcal{N}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Solution:

I have to prove the following:

1. $A\in\mathcal{N}\Rightarrow A^c\in\mathcal{N}$
2. $\{A_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ is a sequence of set of $\mathcal{N}$ then $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\in\mathcal{N}$

For the first one I've done the following:

Let $A\in\mathcal{N}$ then for definition $\phi^{-1}(A)\in \mathcal{M}$ but since $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra $\phi^{-1}(A)^c\in\mathcal{M}$. Now:
\begin{equation}
\phi^{-1}(A)=\{x\in X:\phi(x)\in A\}\Rightarrow\phi^{-1}(A)^c=\{x\in X:\phi(x)\notin A\}\Rightarrow\phi^{-1}(A)^c=\{x\in X:\phi(x)\in A^c\}=\phi^{-1}(A^c)
\end{equation}
and from the last we deduce that $A^c\in \mathcal{N}$.

For the second one I choose $\{A_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ a sequence of set in $\mathcal{N}$, then, for definition of $\mathcal{N}$ we have that $\phi^{-1}(A_k)\in\mathcal{M}$ $\forall k=1,...,n,...$ and that:

$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\phi^{-1}(A_k)\in\mathcal{M}$

Now:

\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\phi^{-1}(A_k)=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\{x\in X:\phi(x)\in A_k\}=\{x\in X:\phi(x)\in\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\}=\phi^{-1}(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k)
\end{equation}

And the last one implies that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\in\mathcal{N}$

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is a correct proof of 1) and 2). But there is a third conidition: $\mathcal N$ is not an empty collection!

Comment: thank you so much, can you give me a hint in order to prove the third one? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: $\phi ^{-1} (\emptyset)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the proof is fine. As noted in the comment, be careful and do not forget the empty set conditions, sometimes it seems trivial but it is a condition, and we love it nonetheless.

Note, just as a remark, how useful it is that the preimage commutes with the complement and the union operations (among others). As an example, this would not be the case for the “image” of a function, that does not commute with the complement operation.